# Running RabbitMQ in docker container

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I am quite new when it comes to RabbitMQ and I am working on a POC to run a C# solution that's using RabbitMQ in a docker container.

I managed to write the docker-compose.yml, dockerfile and run RabbitMQ. However, my solution cannot reach the RabbitMQ host. I think I might be missing some configuration but I cannnot tell what.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  rabbit-sender:
    image: rabbit-sender
    container_name: rabbit-sender
    build: 
        context: ../SenderRabitMQ
        dockerfile: debug.Dockerfile
    env_file: common.env
    networks:
      - rabbitPoc
    expose:
      - "80"

  rabbit-receiver:
    image: rabbit-receiver
    container_name: rabbit-receiver
    build: 
      context: ../ReceiveRabitMQ
      dockerfile: debug.Dockerfile
    env_file: common.env
    networks:
      - rabbitPoc
    expose:
      - "80"

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.7.15
    hostname: rabbitmq
    build: 
      context: rabbit
      dockerfile: debug.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - "./enabled_plugins:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins"
```

debug.Dockerfile

```
Install RabbitMQ
FROM ubuntu:14.04.1

CMD docker pull dockerfile/rabbitmq
CMD docker build -t="dockerfile/rabbitmq" github.com/dockerfile/rabbitmq

FROM dotnet-core-sdk-2.1-debug:latest AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY SenderRabitMQ/SenderRabitMQ.csproj SenderRabitMQ/
RUN dotnet restore SenderRabitMQ/SenderRabitMQ.csproj

# Copy everything else and build
COPY ./ ./
RUN dotnet publish SenderRabitMQ/SenderRabitMQ.csproj -c Debug -o out --no-restore

# Build runtime image
FROM dotnet-core-aspnet-2.1-debug:latest
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-env /app/SenderRabitMQ/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SenderRabitMQ.dll"]
```

RUN command

```
docker run  --hostname myrabbit rabbitmq:3
```

Connecting to RabbitMQ

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "myrabbit:5672" , DispatchConsumersAsync = true };
```

This is the error received when running the RabbitSender that's supposed to post a message to the queue.

```
rabbit-sender      | Unhandled Exception: 
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the 
specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.AggregateException: 
One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed) ---> 
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection 
failed ---> 
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: 
Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672
```

Comment: Is your application, which is trying to communicate with rabbitmq, is also running in a container?

Comment: Yes it is, that's where im getting the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your docker compose sets the RabbitMQ service host name to be rabbitmq and not myrabbit (which is what you're trying to connect to). Try this instead:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "rabbitmq", port = 5672 , DispatchConsumersAsync = true };
```

You also will need the Dockerfile rabbitmq section to be on the same network as the other services:

```
rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.7.15
    hostname: rabbitmq
    build: 
      context: rabbit
      dockerfile: debug.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - rabbitPoc
    volumes:
      - "./enabled_plugins:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I made the changes and I can now see that indeed RabbitMQ is connected to the network (thanks for that!) but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @MonicaS I don't think you need the port in the HostName, it has it's own property. If you're using RabbitMQ.Client that is

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix it sadly. `Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672` . And yes, I am using RabbitMQ.Client.

Comment: Can you hit the management site in your browser using localhost:15672

Comment: Managed to fix it by setting the following host             `var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "host.docker.internal", Port = 5672, DispatchConsumersAsync = true };` Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd try and get it working with the service name personally, the usage of host.docker.internal doesn't smell rite!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
HostName = "http://host.docker.internal:5672"
```

or

```
HostName = "host.docker.internal:5672"
```

instead of

```
HostName = "myrabbit:5672"
```

The reason is:

> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network
>   access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the
>   special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal
>   IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will
>   not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for
>   Windows.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I have tried both of them and I am still getting the same error though  `Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672`     `var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "host.docker.internal:5672", DispatchConsumersAsync = true };`

Comment: a small step which is often overlooked, did you build the containers again after the change? your error messages shows it's still trying to connect on 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yeah, I did a build with --no-cache.

Comment: Fix it! I was indeed building it wrongly. Thanks for your help. The `            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "host.docker.internal", Port = 5672, DispatchConsumersAsync = true };` worked.

Comment: Glad you fixed it, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In docker container,the place where you are making a connection to locally setup rabbitmq, you need to give the host as following

> host.docker.internal

It will work.

Comment: Please provide code example